# Problems with "Not" Operator in Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working on a responsive site and my client wants certain styles to apply to the desktop at 768px but NOT to tablets at that size. I've tried multiple media queries but I can only get Firefox to cooperate. Chrome, Safari and IE all ignore the media query. Here is what I tried.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px), not (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /* styles for desktop only here */
 }
```

I think it has to do with the "not" operator but I don't see that I'm doing anything wrong. It's also worth mentioning that the ipad (in my simulator) ignores the media query which is exactly what I want. I just can't get the Chrome, Safari and IE on my desktop to read the dang thing.

Answer (score 3):

Each and every Media Query string separated by commas should be fully formed (I'm not aware that in the spec *anything* carries over from one to the next ...although *some* browsers may support "shortcuts" here, it's prudent to stick to the lowest common denominator: the spec). (Among other things this makes testing easier since simple text mods allow you to test one Media Query at a time.) And of course "only" and "not" are mutually exclusive options. So I think the syntax should be

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px), not screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
```

(xxx-device-width: and xxx-width: [with inclusion or exclusion of "-device"] refer to the *screen* width and the *viewport/layout* width respectively [which are typically the same for "desktop" devices, and for most handhelds if <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> was specified, but may *not* be the same for smartphones without the "viewport" specification in the HTML source of the page). I don't typically see a mixture of the two in a single Media Query statement, and so [even though I haven't yet tried to understand this example in detail] I suspect something is a bit awry.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell appart tablets and computers with resolution media queries : too much different resolutions on different hardware and no real common rule (have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Tablet_computers), and that's only Androïd !)

You should detect touch support with Javascript, add a class to your HTML tag and build your CSS on this basis, bearing in mind it's not a 100% catch (there are touch computers.)

Try http://www.modernizr.com/ !

Comment: I already use modernizr so I can add .no-touch to everything. It just adds a lot of bloat because then in the rules that follow for the 1024px media query I have to add .no-touch and .touch to everything to match the specificity of the 768px media query. It turns into a mess but maybe that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have suggested alternative approaches.  I'll try and explain why what you were trying didn't work (as expected). I think this would be useful for people trying to get `not` working in media queries.

Negation of media expressions (individual parts like `(min-device-width: 768px)`, as opposed to media queries, which are the full items in the comma-separated list, like `only screen and (min-width: 768px)`) requires CSS Level 4 which (AFAIK) is currently only supported in Firefox.

CSS Level 3 does support negation of full media queries (only), but [if you use the `not` operator, you *must also* specify a media type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#logical_operators).

So a Level 3 media query for 'not a tablet-sized device' would be `not all and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)` (or `not screen and ...` as suggested in [@Chuck Kollars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240454/2511031)).

`not (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)` is not a valid Level 3 query but is a valid Level 4 query.  However, `not` has greater precedence than `and` so it actually means `(not (min-device-width: 768px)) and (max-device-width: 1024px)` which is not what you intended.

The inner CSS rules are applied whenever any of the media queries in the list match.  In other words, the comma (`,`) acts like an `or` operator.  So what you were trying actually means 'at least 768px wide, or not a tablet', which will match almost everything (or would do with the media type added to the second query so it can be parsed by Level 3 browsers).

The only way I can think of to achieve what you were intending with CSS Level 3 would be something like

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (min-device-width: 1025px), 
       screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 767px) {
}
```

(Though the second media query now looks probably superfluous and unlikely to match.)

But as stated in [@mddw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622286/2511031), this won't exclude all tablets and may even exclude some other devices.